# Converting array formula having SMALL function into an evaluate function

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas, evaluate

I have  the following code for array formula with SMALL function that works and writes result into a cell:

```
Dim strColLetter As String
Dim strActiveColLetter As String
Dim strColLetter As String
Dim strActiveColLetter As String
Dim strBulkNum As String
Dim intLastCol As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim intLastRow As Long
Dim rngProntoItemDataBulkNum As Range
Dim rngProntoItemDataRefNum As Range
Dim wksh As Worksheet
Dim wbk As Workbook

Set wbk = Workbooks("Master - Pronto_Item_Data.xlsx")
Set wksh = Workbooks("Master - Pronto_Item_Data.xlsx").Sheets("Pronto_Data")
intLastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WorkFile4").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
intLastCol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WorkFile4").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
strColLetter = Split(Cells(1, intLastCol + 2).Address, "$")(1)
Set rngProntoItemDataBulkNum = wksh.Range("ProntoItemDataBulkNum")
Set rngProntoItemDataRefNum = wksh.Range("ProntoItemDataRefNum")
For j = 3 To intLastRow - 1 'looping through the rows
   For i = 1 To 5 'looping across five columns
    strActiveColLetter = Split(Cells(1, intLastCol + 1 + i).Address, "$")(1)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WorkFile4").Cells(j, intLastCol + 1 + i).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('[Master - Pronto_Item_Data.xlsx]Pronto_Data'!" & rngProntoItemDataBulkNum.Address(False, True) & ", SMALL(IF('[Master - Pronto_Item_Data.xlsx]Pronto_Data'!" & rngProntoItemDataRefNum.Address(False, True) & "=$A" & j & ",ROW('[Master - Pronto_Item_Data.xlsx]Pronto_Data'!" & rngProntoItemDataRefNum.Address(False, True) & ")),COLUMNS($" & strColLetter & "$" & j & ":" & strActiveColLetter & j & "))),"""")"
    strBulkNum = Evaluate("=IFERROR(INDEX('[Master - Pronto_Item_Data.xlsx]Pronto_Data'!$A:$A, SMALL(IF('[Master - Pronto_Item_Data.xlsx]Pronto_Data'!$N:$N=$A" & j & ",ROW('[Master - Pronto_Item_Data.xlsx]Pronto_Data'!$N:$N)),COLUMNS($" & strColLetter &  "$" & j & ":" & strActiveColLetter & j & "))),"""")")
   Next i
Next j
```

I am struggling to convert this array formula code into an EVALUATE function and store into strBulkNum variable. Currently it gives an error.
I would appreciate any help in writing the EVALUATE expression for the above array formula for each instance of i and j.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you get at what line?

Comment: I unable to write correct syntax for the Evaluate function when trying to use the quotes for the variable. The code works fine.

Comment: I get Compile error in my last statement : strBulkNum = Evaluate(...)

Comment: You don't want quotes around the column letter - that part should look just like the `formulaarray` line above it.

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks for your comments. Could you kindly post the statement with the correction. That would be a great help!!

Comment: You are also missing quotes at the end of that line or maybe you have an additional bit that you don't need.. I haven't checked the full line

Comment: Any help in rewriting this line is most welcome. Going nuts over using the correct quote-wrap syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I've finally made the last line for EVALUATE to work. It was the syntax errors as pointed out by Rory.

Comment: Note - you can simplify your formula by stripping out all of the `'[Master - Pronto_Item_Data.xlsx]Pronto_Data'!` and using `wksh.Evaluate(formulaHere)` - this will evaluate the formula *in the context of wksh* as opposed to the default `Application.Evaluate()` , which uses the activesheet.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Point noted!